# Mouse-over image markers that onclick lightbox

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, lightbox

I couldn't quite think of the right way of wording the question but basically I want something very similar to what google maps looks like:

**Choose a number of images (these images will be simple list of tabs that when clicked have a fade transition on the page) but on each of these images clicking a certain part (such as a marker or highlighted area) will bring up a small lightbox popup perhaps containing simplified information and a "more info" link.**

So far from researching I've found a lot of map plugins that create an svg image but I'm not sure yet whether the images used will be maps or for example a picture of a building or something. There also seems to be a lot of different possibilites with fancybox for displaying html elements in a stylish way onclick. I'm just confused as to how you make it so clicking certain areas of an image will open different popups.

Any help on the best way to go about this would be nice

-Matt

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11300063/1055987 ... don't miss to check the demo here http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/galleryFromImageMap_02jul12.html

Comment: thanks this looks very promising, I will look into incorporating this into the current slider I'm using.