# FancyBox + Hotspots/Image Maps = Multi-Image Photo Gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, imagemap

I am trying something new for a Photography Website portfolio ... I decided to create one image that is of "mosaic" type layout in Photoshop. Then when brought into Dreamweaver, placed hotspots over each piece of the mosaic to call up fancyBox to view that particular photo gallery (like Weddings, Family Portraits, etc.). Now I'm trying to figure out the code needed to show multiple images from clicking on one hotspot .... something isn't working. I have searched all over and can't seem to find any code change that will work. Help please?!?!?!?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11300063/1055987

Comment: I have tried many "fixes" that I found through other people's questions on here and even some jsfiddle examples from others but can't seem to make it work.

@JFK I did check that out before asking my question. This is what I am looking to do [link](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/galleryFromImageMap_02jul12.html) but it isn't working for me ... not sure why other than its me doing something wrong.

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK! However I'm  now using Lightbox2. But in the javascript code you can link LightBox to <a href> & <area> for hotspots/image maps!!!! YAY!!!!!!!